# How to apply ARRAYFORMULA when using FILTER function in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, array-formulas

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to apply `ARRATFORMULA` into my formula in column C but I have no idea on how to make it. I'm not sure whether it is possible to use `ARRAYFORMULA` together with FILTER function, if no, is there any other way (except script) that I can use so that I'm not required to drag down the formula to each and every cells?

This is my sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qYGOKmElgaTxZLeHzcgB4fjZsI411xHpxrj8k_-osdI/edit#gid=0

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is exactly you're trying to achieve? Do you want one formula to filter against all 4 "value" columns in "sheet 2"?

Comment: yes, I just want to have one formula in cell `C3` and no other formula in the rest of the rows in column C, but at the same time can achieve what `FIlter` function is achieving now

Comment: Is there any significance to the other columns on Sheet2? Right now, you're only checking column D against your "condition". Is the idea to check all of the columns or just D?

Comment: Just column D in Sheet2, Column B,C,E can be ignored

Comment: Okay, I don't think this is do-able without some fudging or extra assumptions.  Oversimplifying, Arrayformula works on functions that don't normally already take an array as input.  However, you want to scan a whole array each time (Sheet2) and compare to a single date and a single number (which vary - these are what you want to array-ify). But arrayformula can't determine there is only a single number ever going to be outputted (because filter, query, etc. give array outputs in general) and therefore can't compile an array corresponding to your varying inputs.

Comment: I think a possible approach to experiment with could be to do some big product (matrix) of all of the possibilities and then filter that by the ones which match the conditions... But I'm guessing the fact you want only a single cell formula is for convenience rather than necessity since you can simply use what you have on each row of new conditions...?

Comment: Yes, if that is the case then it's okay, I just leave it as it is for now. Thanks for your reply!